# LogisticRegression TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, logistic-regression

I am trying to perform LogisticRegression using statsmodels and I run into this problem. I've been searching for it but could not find how to fix it and I'm not sure which part of my preprocessing is causing this problem.

Here is my code:

```
df['Class'].replace('benign',2, inplace=True)
df['Class'].replace('malignant',4, inplace=True)
df.replace('?',10**9,inplace=True)
df.isnull().values.any()#this gives false, data has no missing value
X = df.drop(['Class','Code'], 1)
X = pd.DataFrame({"Constant":np.ones(len(X))}).join(pd.DataFrame(X))
y = df['Class']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
X_train.astype(int)
y_train.astype(int)
X_train = np.array(X_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)
```

The error was raised here:

```
clf = sm.Logit(y_train, X_train)
```

And this is the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "<ipython-input-204-dfe5f93d6f95>", line 1, in <module>
    clf = sm.Logit(y_train, X_train)

  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\discrete\discrete_model.py", line 402, in __init__
    super(BinaryModel, self).__init__(endog, exog, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\discrete\discrete_model.py", line 155, in __init__
    super(DiscreteModel, self).__init__(endog, exog, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py", line 212, in __init__
    super(LikelihoodModel, self).__init__(endog, exog, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py", line 63, in __init__
    **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py", line 88, in _handle_data
    data = handle_data(endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py", line 630, in handle_data
    **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py", line 79, in __init__
    self._handle_constant(hasconst)

  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py", line 131, in _handle_constant
    const_idx = np.where(self.exog.ptp(axis=0) == 0)[0].squeeze()

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I'm new to Machine Learning.

Comment: check that your X_train  has only numerical values, i.e. should have dtype float64. Note that your `.astype(int)` does not make inplace changes and will have no effect.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing this out. The problem has been fixed :).